# Recoding variables in a list

Tags: r, list, function, lapply, recode

I guess I am writing in the spirit of "no question is too easy", I am just an average Stata-user social scientist approaching R for the first time and having endless nights facing it... Please have mercy!

I am working with a comparative dataset from 20 countries (about 20,000 observations, quite balanced across countries).
I have to perform a set of quite computationally-intense MCMC simulations and I have thus decided to split the df into a list containing 20 (country-specific) df, and proceed with `lapply()`. (I read that it is more efficient to avoid `for` loops on R, right?)

My most immediate problem is that I am unable to preprocess the elements within the various df contained in the list. In particular, I have to recode a set of 15 variables, these are integers ranging from 0 to 10 that includes SPSS typical values for missing cases: `77 88, 89, 99, 999`. I want to recode these values to `NA` and then do some little additional transformations: center on 0, define two df objects `T` and `TT` with two different sets of variables to be later used in the simulations. This task has to be repeated across 20 different country-specific list elements that compose the "master" list "ees2009split".

```
ees2009split <- vector("list", 20)
ees2009split <- split(ees2009, ees2009$t102) # t102 is the country identifier
names(ees2009split) <- country.names[1:2]    # rename list objects with country names
```

So here is my list (sorry I am unable to provide a reproducible example):

```
    > str(ees2009split)
List of 20
 $         Austria :'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  17 variables:
  ..$ t102   : int [1:1000] 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 ...
  ..$ q46    : int [1:1000] 77 2 5 5 5 77 5 5 5 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p1 : int [1:1000] 77 3 5 4 77 77 5 1 89 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p2 : int [1:1000] 77 8 7 6 77 77 5 6 5 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p3 : int [1:1000] 77 10 10 9 77 77 5 7 7 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p4 : int [1:1000] 77 10 9 8 77 77 5 7 4 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p5 : int [1:1000] 77 2 5 3 77 77 5 1 3 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p6 : int [1:1000] 77 4 89 5 77 77 89 2 89 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p7 : int [1:1000] 77 3 89 6 77 77 89 3 5 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p8 : int [1:1000] 77 1 0 0 77 77 5 0 89 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p9 : int [1:1000] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p10: int [1:1000] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p11: int [1:1000] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p12: int [1:1000] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p13: int [1:1000] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p14: int [1:1000] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p15: int [1:1000] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
 $         Belgium :'data.frame':   1002 obs. of  17 variables:
  ..$ t102   : int [1:1002] 1056 1056 1056 1056 1056 1056 1056 1056 1056 1056 ...
  ..$ q46    : int [1:1002] 5 0 77 88 77 88 5 2 77 5 ...
  ..$ q47_p1 : int [1:1002] 88 5 77 77 6 77 5 77 5 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p2 : int [1:1002] 88 10 77 77 8 77 89 77 10 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p3 : int [1:1002] 88 7 77 77 5 77 3 77 0 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p4 : int [1:1002] 88 10 77 77 10 77 10 77 10 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p5 : int [1:1002] 88 0 77 77 4 77 4 77 5 77 ...
  ..$ q47_p6 : int [1:1002] 99 99 77 99 99 77 99 77 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p7 : int [1:1002] 99 99 77 99 99 77 99 77 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p8 : int [1:1002] 99 99 88 99 99 77 99 77 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p9 : int [1:1002] 99 99 77 99 99 77 99 77 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p10: int [1:1002] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p11: int [1:1002] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p12: int [1:1002] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p13: int [1:1002] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p14: int [1:1002] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
  ..$ q47_p15: int [1:1002] 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99 ...
```

etc... until country 20.

I defined two functions to be called with `lapply()`, the functions `rename()` and `recode()`:

```
rename <- function(x) {
    # renaming
    names(x) <- gsub("q46", "lr.self", names(x))
    names(x) <- gsub("q47_p", "lr.p", names(x))
    return(x)
}
```

So far so good:

```
> processed.dat <- lapply(ees2009split, renaming)
> str(processed.dat)
List of 20
 $         Austria :'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  17 variables:
  ..$ t102   : int [1:1000] 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 1040 ...
  ..$ lr.self: int [1:1000] 77 2 5 5 5 77 5 5 5 77 ...
  ..$ lr.p1  : int [1:1000] 77 3 5 4 77 77 5 1 89 77 ...
# I omit the rest...
```

With the recoding function I am having hard time instead:

```
recoding <- function(x){
        # recode missing values
        x$lr.self[lr.self %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p1[lr.p1 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p2[lr.p2 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p3[lr.p3 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p4[lr.p4 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p5[lr.p5 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p6[lr.p6 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p7[lr.p7 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p8[lr.p8 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p9[lr.p9 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p10[lr.p10 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p11[lr.p11 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p12[lr.p12 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p13[lr.p13 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p14[lr.p14 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA
        x$lr.p15[lr.p15 %in% c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999)] <- NA

        x$T <- cbind(lr.self, lr.p1, lr.p2, lr.p3, lr.p4, lr.p5, lr.p6, lr.p7, lr.p8, lr.p9, lr.p10, lr.p11, lr.p12, lr.p13, lr.p14, lr.p15) 
        T <- T - 5      # centering on 0

        lrself.resc <- T[,1]    # rescaled lr.self
        TT <- T[,-1]            # whole matrix rescaled

        N <- nrow(TT)
        q <- ncol(TT)
        z <- TT
        x$dat.list <- list(lr.self=lr.self, lr.p1=lr.p1, lr.p2=lr.p2, lr.p3=lr.p3, lr.p4=lr.p4, lr.p5=lr.p5, lr.p6=lr.p6, lr.p7=lr.p7, lr.p8=lr.p8, lr.p9=lr.p9, lr.p10=lr.p10, lr.p11=lr.p11, lr.p12=lr.p12, lr.p13=lr.p13, lr.p14=lr.p14, lr.p15=lr.p15, T=T, TT=TT, lrself.resc, N=N, q=q, z=z)
        return(x$dat.list)
}
```

This is the output:

```
> processed.dat <- lapply(ees2009split, recoding)
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'lr.self' not found
Called from: FUN(X[[1L]], ...)
Browse[1]>
```

1) How should I recode variables within a data frame that in contained in a list with `lapply()`? more broadly, how do I insert objects within the country df within the function?
2) On a more general stance, it is correct this way of proceeding? Splitting, defining task-specific functions, call them with `lapply()`, and finally recombine?

Thank you for any suggestion or comment.
Andrea

Comment: If I were in your position, I'd first convert the European Election Study Data into a tidy format, then process the NAs, then normalize. Unless you're running it on a laptop with 4gb RAM, or have some reasons to do so beyond computing limitations, I don't think you need to split the data.

Comment: Tell the function you use for importing the data how `NA` is encoded and it will take care of that for you.

Comment: Regarding the `recode`, instead of repeating `val <- c(77, 88, 89, 98, 99, 999); lapply(processed.dat, function(x) {x[] <-lapply(x, function(.x) {.x[.x %in% val] <- NA;.x}); x})`

Comment: @SerbanTanasa: thanks for the suggestion. I could easily preprocess the data in Stata, save 20 df and create a list on R. But is it really that complicated to recode within a list in R? If possible I would rather learn something and provide a single-program replication script...

@Roland: I am using `read.dta()`. I don't find a way to introduce explicit values for mv on the `help(read.dta)`. [This](http://www.r-bloggers.com/missing-values-and-column-types-when-reading-data-into-r/) could be useful for someone in my same condition working with `read.table`.

Comment: @akrun: recoding works adjusting your code (ees2009split[['Austria']] and the other list elements are df, not lists. I added `x<-as.list(x)` in the anonymous function. Somebody could be more informative? This is the way to go? Chains of `lapply()`? Thanks again.

Comment: @R.newby a `data.frame` is a list with its elements have the same length.  Based on the example you provided, my code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for the data cleaning. I use the library `gdata` which you'll probably have to install with this command: `install.packages('gdata')`. In it you will find a most useful function, namely `unknownToNA()`. See the example below.
As I said, I prefer to do the cleaning before I split up the data. I took the liberty of using the [EES 2009 dataset](https://dbk.gesis.org/dbksearch/SDesc2.asp?no=5055&search=5055&search2=&db=D) as well:

```
library(foreign)
library(gdata)
#setwd("/Data/sample")
#list.files()
mydata <- read.dta("ZA5055_v1-1-0.dta")
keepvars <- grep("^q46|^q47|^t102",names(mydata), value=T)
mydata2 <- subset(mydata, select=keepvars)
rm(mydata)
str(mydata2)
head(mydata2)
naval <- c(77, 88, 89, 99, 999)
mydata3 <- unknownToNA(mydata2, unknown=list(.default=naval))
head(mydata3)

#      t102 q46 q47_p1 q47_p2 q47_p3 q47_p4 q47_p5 q47_p6 q47_p7 q47_p8 q47_p9 q47_p10 q47_p11 q47_p12 q47_p13
# 1 Austria  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
# 2 Austria   2      3      8     10     10      2      4      3      1     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
# 3 Austria   5      5      7     10      9      5     NA     NA      0     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
# 4 Austria   5      4      6      9      8      3      5      6      0     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
# 5 Austria   5     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
# 6 Austria  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
# q47_p14 q47_p15
# 1      NA      NA
# 2      NA      NA
# 3      NA      NA
# 4      NA      NA
# 5      NA      NA
# 6      NA      NA
```

If you prefer to split first for some reason, here you go:

```
    library(gdata)
    ees2009split <- split(mydata2, mydata2$t102)
    ees2009split <- unknownToNA(ees2009split, unknown=list(.default=list(naval)))
    head(ees2009split[[1]])


     t102 q46 q47_p1 q47_p2 q47_p3 q47_p4 q47_p5 q47_p6 q47_p7 q47_p8 q47_p9 q47_p10 q47_p11 q47_p12 q47_p13
1 Austria  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2 Austria   2      3      8     10     10      2      4      3      1     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3 Austria   5      5      7     10      9      5     NA     NA      0     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
4 Austria   5      4      6      9      8      3      5      6      0     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5 Austria   5     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
6 Austria  NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
  q47_p14 q47_p15
1      NA      NA
2      NA      NA
3      NA      NA
4      NA      NA
5      NA      NA
6      NA      NA
```

I'm afraid I don't understand your next steps enough to help further.
But generally for scaling I use the `scale` function, which centers on 0 and normalizes:

```
head(scale(mydata3[,-1]))
```

Comment: Thank you @Serban-tanasa, that works and simplified a lot. I need to split because I have to undertake country-by-country analyses. Thus, one alternative would be to work on a country-basis with 27 separated code chunks, one for each df. In Stata I would have run a `for` cycle using the 27 datasets accordingly. On R, for what I have been reading it appears that `lapply()` on a list with the 27df in it works more efficiently.

Comment: @R.newby You can always split it *after* you finish cleaning. Unless normalization is to be done on a country by country basis, you can do that before splitting as well. PS: Nothing wrong with a for loop. The point of the code is a) for it to work b) for you to understand what it does and only a distant c) to be highly efficient.

Comment: @R.newby Google "split-apply-combine". It's often not necessary for you to use `split` and `lapply`, because their are more convenient and more efficient alternatives (see packages dplyr or data.table).

Comment: @SerbanTanasa This (`unknownToNA`) is very useful (+1)